# ansible no changed but if i select one host then works?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I write on a YAML-Script that change the permission on the /home/* directories. If I test on a single Server with "host: 172.16.11.74" then work the Script perfectly. But if I change the "host: 172.16.11.*" can Ansible reach, login every server and give an "ok" back. But nothing change? How what I do wrong??

```
---
- name: "starte chmod 750 für alle /home verzeichnisse"
  hosts: 172.16.11.*
  become: yes
 
  tasks:

    - name: ls /home/*
      find:
        paths: /home
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
      register: found_directories

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ found_directories.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

    - name: chmod 750 /home/* alle user im home
      command: find {{ item.path }} -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec chmod -c 0750 {} \;
      with_items: "{{ found_directories.files }}"
      register: chmod_result
      changed_when: "chmod_result.stdout != \"\""
```

I expecting that Ansible execute the Scrip on every Server

Comment: And what should that syntax do? Sniff your network to see if there is any server matching `172.16.11.*`? Run the playbook for all the IPs from `172.16.11.0` to `172.16.11.255`? No, that type of wildcard is not possible. You might want to read about inventories, though: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html

Answer (score -1):

a colleague found the error. The hosts list must be clean. In addition, all servers must be reachable. If not, the YAML script must contain the following commands:

**ignore_unreachable: true**

**ignore_errors: true**

if not ansible with skip the complete list.